# Do subscription promo codes work with the subscription test flow?

Tags: android, google-play, subscription, promotion-code

I'm trying to test promo codes for a subscription in my app. The promo-code is for a 30 day free trial.

I'm currently testing my subscriptions with a test user and it follows the 3 min free trial, 5 min for a month and all that according to this Google sheet https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#testing-subscriptions

What I'm doing right now is wait for the 3 min free trial to pass. After that I also wait another 5 min for the first billing to happen.
After that I enter a promo code.

I would expect to receive an email from Google Play saying that the promo code is redeemed and a 0 value invoice after another 5 minute month is over.

What actually happens is that the test flow presented at the link above just goes on until it ends. As if the promo code was never entered. There is also no email from Google regarding the promo code, I just receive the usual monthly invoices.

If I try to use the promo code again it says that it has already been redeemed.

I tried looking in the documentation for something about promo-codes not working with the test flow but I didn't manage to find anything regarding that.

Does anyone know if the promo codes don't work with the subscription test flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know if the promo codes don't work with the subscription test flow?

**Yes. Promo codes are not working with Subscription test flow.**

> What I'm doing right now is wait for the 3 min free trial to pass. After that I also wait another 5 min for the first billing to happen. After that I enter a promo code.

**How did you adding promo code in your subscription? as there are no UI to redeem promo code in "purchase flow" during Test Subscription.**

If you are redeeming code from Google Play app, after purchasing subscription. Then your promo code free trial will not add to your subscription. You need to consume that promo code, to use new trial period. See [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_promo#Support-promo)

Comment: As a beta tester you can still redeem a code in the PlayStore. But as I said there was no effect. What I wanted to know was if I can use the test flow to also test promo codes. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Has there been any update to this? I would like to test the promo code. I can now apply a promo code but it seems to be real time. So I can only test one every couple of days. Maybe, I have not tried to apply a second promo code to test another scenario because I am still in the first free trial. I need to make sure this works but dont know how I can test all the scenarios google suggests to test with out it taking multiple accounts, days and/or subscriptions. Does anyone know how we can test promo code subscriptions quickly and in a sandbox?